# How to re-write this linq from query syntax to method syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, syntax

As in title, how to rewrite this linq query into method syntax?

```
(from row in recordsEpP
 where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Column20)
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Column14)
        &&  string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Column8))
 select new ReportDto{
     Status = "P",
     ContractNumber = row.ContractNumber,
     Count = 1
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Any attempt so far? It sounds very much like you're asking us to do it for you.

Comment: My question is why?  `recordsEpP.Where(...).Select(...new...).ToList();`  No complexity is reduced, not easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @paqogomez, this is just for a sake of knowing ... I am just starting linq and came up with query syntax yet did not actually understand method syntax... your example made it very clear. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
recordsEpP.Where(row=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Column20) &&                 
                       !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Column14) &&
                        string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Column8)
         ).Select(row => new ReportDto{
            Status = "P",
            ContractNumber = row.ContractNumber,
            Count = 1
         }).ToList();
```